# Solution to PDEs and inequalities

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working on a modelling problem, and I have derived the following result about two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ that are continuous and differentiable in both the arguments--

$$\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)}{f(x,y)} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = h(x)<0$$

$$\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)}{f(x,y)} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x,y)}{g(x,y)}<0$$

These appear to be partial derivatives of the natural log of the functions, so I tried some exponential functions, but in all the tries I made,whenever the first held true, the second turned 0.

I am new to PDEs, so I may be missing some very basic thing.

I would appreciate every answer, either solving it, providing resources to study to be able to myself solve it (given I am new to PDEs) or at least giving examples of functions that satisfy these conditions if not the general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing $u = \ln f - \ln g$, this tells you $\partial_x u = h(x)$, so $u = H(x) + C(y)$ where $H$ is an antiderivative of $h$ ($H$ is decreasing since $h<0$), and $C(y)$ is a constant with respect to $x$ that can still depend on $y$.

The second equation tells you that $\partial_y u = C'(y) < 0$, so $C$ is decreasing.

Since $e^u = f/g$ we deduce that
$$
f(x,y) = g(x,y) e^{H(x)} e^{C(y)}
$$
Where $H = \int h$ and $C$ are decreasing functions. You can not get more than that.